# how to unlink between app and facebook in facebook-sdk?

Tags: android, facebook, unlink

first, I'am sorry. i can't english well.

i have a problem in facebook sdk.

now i am developing login with facebook sdk.

and logout too.

***but i can't find unlink api between my-app and facebook.***

for example, some user using my app do not want to use my app more.

so he needs to ban me(or my app) in order to protect his data on facebook.

do you understand me? T.T please help me.

following flow is when the user unlinks the app himself directly.

but i want to do this in my app menu with login, logout, etc.

Menu Flow : (in facebook app settings) Apps -> Logged in with Facebook -> (choice a app) -> Remove App

Answer (score 1):

```
FB.api("/me/permissions","DELETE",function(response){
    console.log(response); //gives true on app delete success 
});
```

You need a active access token of user to do this

Using Facebook sdk

```
new Request(
   session,
    "/me/permissions/{permission-to-revoke}",
    null,
    HttpMethod.DELETE,
    new Request.Callback() {
        public void onCompleted(Response response) {
            /* handle the result */
        }
    }
).executeAsync();
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. but i want solution in android platform. can i use this code in android(with facebook sdk)?

Comment: thank you!!!!!!!! I was surprised at your knowledge. You are my eternal master. i love u.